# Serilization data in foramt its getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, serialization

I have written some code to display the data in some format in file

```
public List<TimeSheetVO> getEmployeedetails(Connection con2, java.sql.Date dbdate) {

    timesheetlist=new ArrayList<TimeSheetVO>();
    try {
        String query = SQLutilConstants.GET_TIMESHEET;
        psmt=con2.prepareStatement(query);
        psmt.setDate(1,dbdate );
        rs=psmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            TimeSheetVO  timeSheetVO=new TimeSheetVO();
            timeSheetVO.setEMP_ID(rs.getString("EMP_ID"));  
            //timeSheetVO.setATTENDANCE_DATE(rs.getString("ATTENDANCE_DATE").replaceAll("[-+.^:,]", ""));
            String attendance= rs.getString("ATTENDANCE_DATE");
            String[] splitattendance=attendance.split("-");
            timeSheetVO.setATTENDANCE_DATE(splitattendance[2]+splitattendance[1]+splitattendance[0]); 

            String intimetime= rs.getString("IN_TIME");
            String[] splitintime=intimetime.split(":");
            timeSheetVO.setIN_TIME(splitintime[0]+splitintime[1]);

            String outtime=rs.getString("OUT_TIME");
            String[] splitouttime=outtime.split(":");
            timeSheetVO.setOUT_TIME(splitouttime[0]+splitouttime[1]);

            System.out.println("timesheetVo"+timeSheetVO.getATTENDANCE_DATE());
            timesheetlist.add(timeSheetVO);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  timesheetlist;
}
```

Here am using one more **method** and passing **timesheetlist** as **timesheetlist2**:
But here displaying only one row remaining rows are not displayed for that corresponding **Attendancedate** getting **NullPointerException**

```
public  String getTimesheet(List<TimeSheetVO> timesheetlist2, java.sql.Date dbdate) {           
    try {
        String fieloc=MessageConstants.timesheetpath; 
        File file=new File(fieloc+dbdate+".txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for(TimeSheetVO time: timesheetlist2) {
            bw.write(time+" ");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            path=file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        bw.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  path;
}
```

Comment: First format your question for better responses

Comment: Can you also provide the stacktrace here?

Comment: What's the format of the attendance date, are you sure its using '-' as a separator? Please print the values that you are getting from the database.

Answer (score -1):

First check how many records are returning from the query execution.
then check the size of timesheetlist after the loop.
Surely you will get some clue.

Comment: I guess this should go in as a comment, its not an answer.

Comment: Again SO should consider it's reputation check before posting comments. It's creating some problems for all new users

Comment: @rookieB I did not get you.By default 50 required for comments

Comment: @Deepak Exactly that. Because of this check , the new users are not able to post comments forcing them to post as answer which should be a comment and then get some DV. There was a discussion in SO about this but i don't see any fruits

Comment: @rookieB Agree with you